# window.open() returns undefined when called from setTimeout on Android

Tags: javascript, android

I am having strange behaviour on my Android emulator. window.open() always returns undefined when called from setTimeout or callback function e.g. AJAX callback. However window.open() successfully opens a popup when called from an event handler e.g. onclick
here is sample code:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fnc()
    {
      setTimeout(function() { alert(window.open('about:blank')) }, 100);
    }
    </script>
    <input type="button" onclick="fnc()" value="push me">
    </body>
</html>
```

In the example alert(window.open('about:blank')) shows 'undefined' and the popup is not created
The same function works when called straight from fnc()

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect it's just ordinary popup-blocking behavior.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with javascript in a Xul app, so its not Android's problem. I suggest you remove the Android tag.

Comment: @Pointy it's not, same problem here in a desktop app (using Xul)

Comment: @Andrey are you still using this account?

Comment: @Tom Brito well in a *web* application it's definitely the case that you cannot open a window with `window.open()` from a timeout handler.

Comment: @Pointy not the case here, I building a desktop Xul-based app.

Comment: I found my error, I had rewriten the window.open function and was returning nothing..

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function go(){
                window.open('about:blank');
            }
            function fnc()
            {
                var buttonnode= document.createElement('input');
                buttonnode.setAttribute('type','button');
                buttonnode.setAttribute('name','sal');
                buttonnode.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
                document.body.appendChild(buttonnode);

                buttonnode.onclick = go;

                setTimeout(function() { buttonnode.click() }, 100);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="fnc()" value="do later"><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean `return window.open('about:blank');` inside `go()`?

Comment: The above code works for me on android 2.2 devices - mind you it is somewhat of a hack...